# How to edit this Typo3 menu?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, templates, typo3, typoscript, typo3-7.6.x

I have a one page sample site using the bootstrap_package / Introduction package for Typo3 version 7.6.10.

The problem is I am a complete newbie to Typo3 and need help converting the navigation menu. I want them to be anchors to sections in the page.

In more detail, From what I see in the backend, there is no (editable) menu; all of the navigation links on the front are coming from the pages that I create in the backend. Is there a way to override this function?
Just to be clear, I checked the typoscript and the "setup" column is empty. All of the typoscript is located in ts adn txt files in the server.

[image] 
[image]

Comment: What you could do to get frontend anchor menu is either to create a menu content element and link to specific content. Or create pages with shortcut property to link to anchors.

Comment: did you give up on typo3 ?

Comment: thx, I did the italian on helmut's site ... ask me if you want to know more, keen to help ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are really a newbie I suggest you start again using a complete different approach ... the bootstrap package is badly documented and complicated to grasp.

[ext:t3sbootstrap](https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/t3sbootstrap) offers anchor links in the one-page layout, it is well documented for beginners (maybe no English) and you'll be able to grasp many best practices and typo3 fundamentals to learn by example ...

If you need to produce your site quickly you can ! then you can tweak step by step once you see how its done with this extension ...

it has its dedicated web site : [t3sbootstrap.de](http://www.t3sbootstrap.de/)

let me know if you're interested, I'll give you some pointers to start if you wish ...

Comment: **important** write your own extension next to the t3sbootstrap one to register your personalisation ... you can fil this with just the parts you want custom ...

Answer (score 0):

The default TYPO3 bootstrap_package is by default not suited as a one-page template.

In order to adjust the template to convert it to a one-page solution, you have to adjust your typoscript and site structure accordingly - and add a bit of javascript, too.

If you keep the content on only one page, a section menu might help you.

Answer (score -1):

To edit one page in the page tree you must click with the right hand click of the mouse.There it will open a menu from where you can edit the page.

Second possibility would be to click on the root page and select the module list in the left module panel.
There you will see a page list from where you can edit the pages.

Comment: Not an answer to the question. OP wants to know how to edit the menu on the front end. Not how to edit a page