# How to install TYPO3 on windows 7 with wampp

Tags: windows, xampp, typo3, wampserver

I would appreciate if someone can assist me install TYPO3 on Windows wamp server. I have worked on this for some weeks now on both Linux and Windows, but apparently this is something small I am missing.

Here is what I have done on Windows 7, following guidance given on several links I was not able to list in this post:

1. I have installed wamp and when I start it it shows all services running;
2. I created my folder "vhost1" in which I put my documents (i.e. in C:\wamp\www\vhost1).
3. I have copied typo3_src-6-10 (later replaced by typo3_src-8.4.0) into vhost1 and made the following links-mklink /D typo3_src C:\wamp\www\weaconsort\typo3_src\typo3_src-x.x.x \ mklink /D typo3 typo3_src/typo3 \ mklink /D index.php typo3_src/index.php
4. When I point to "http://localhost/vhost1" in my browser I get "Internal Server Error", but when I point to "http://locahost" I get the index page with my document folder under "Your Projects".
5. Clicking on my document folder gives me "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage"

I cannot go further than this.
I have tried to change Document root to "c:/wamp/www/vhost1" in "http.conf", "httpd-ssl.conf and httpd-vhosts.conf, no avail.
Will appreciate any assistance

Comment: did you give up ?

Comment: throughout my interaction with Zilore I got that he never understood how to basically install typo3, that was probably the reason why it did not run on wampp, xampp works fine but probably there is no need to substitute wampp ... (if you have trouble, the answer stands for the basic install)

Answer (score 0):

I have all running on windows 7 with no trouble ... I'm no wizard at all, so first change is that I have **xampp** installed, no symlinks, I just place in htdocs ...

If you want to go down this road I'll assist you with all questions, I've even got imagemagick up and running:

1. get rid of wampp (hope you're not using it for other development)
2. [download xampp 1.8.3](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/files/XAMPP%20Windows/1.8.3/xampp-win32-1.8.3-5-VC11-installer.exe/download) and install that
3. download typo3 (I suggest 7.6.11, because you'll find lots more extensions and I think v8 runs on php7 !!) and place it in htdocs.
4. rename the folder to a testname, and save an empty file named FIRST_INSTALL in the folder. `[directory structure for typo3 installation: rename typo3_src-7.6.11 to testname]`
   [image: directory structure for installation: rename typo3_src-7.6.11 to testname]
5. start up xampp and go to 'localhost/phpmyadmin/, create there a database 'testname' (I use collation utf8_general_ci but you can leave that)
6. now go to 'localhost/testname/' in your browser, and follow the instructions ... (I think you can ignore the warnings at the start), when you arrive at the database select the one just created with user 'root' and blank password.
7. at the end of the install you'll be asked if you want to start with an empty installation or if you want to fill with the introduction, that's where you insert the package !!
8. keep me posted and I update my answer to resolve where you stall

**TYPO3** *- inspiring people to share!*

Comment: Thanks @webMan, I will back to ask your help after I install xampp

Comment: @ZiloreMumba fine, I'm here until noon, let's get you rolling !!

Comment: Here's what I have done so far. 1) installed xampp and apache and mysql are runnin, 2) created a folder typo3cms inside c:\xampp\htdocs and inside typo3cms I have put introduction-2.3.0 (typo3). When I put localhost in borwser it adds xampp, i.e localhost/xampp then I have object not found. Same if I put localhost/htdocs but localhost/typo3cms showa a directory-introduction-2.3.0

Comment: try first something more simple, so you did put the folder typo3_src-7.6.11 in htdocs ? you need to download typo3_src-7-6-11.zip, then unzip and then place it in htdocs ...

Comment: you just saw now that I updated my answer didn't you ... you skipped installing typo3 all together, the introduction is an extension ... I suspect wampp would have worked ...

Comment: Yes I have just unpacked typo3_src-7.6.11 and placed the folder in htdocs/typo3cms. localhost/typo3cms in my browser says thanks for downloading typo3 and advises to create FIRST_INSTALL in documentroot, which I have done, but I still have the same page (create FIRST_INSTALL). What do I do? OK FIRST_INSTALL was not in typo3_src-7.6.11, now that it is , I seem to be making progress. I will come back

Comment: in the root of your new site... not htdocs ... you are minutes away from the first local typo3 site !! (do not forget to click the 'V' for accepting my answer)

Comment: I know that you installed the introduction package, that is very hard and confusing to personalize for a beginner !!! check this out for doing your own site [t3sbootstrap](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40017504/5353105) ...

Comment: am at 40% complete when I put in a username and password and press continue I get "connection to database unsuccessful" but I was not prompted to create a database. Should I click "I do not use mysql"?

Comment: go to localhost/phpmyadmin/ and create one !! (read carefully once my answer from point 5 on) ...

Comment: OK I created the database but still getting "connection not successful"

Comment: I'd say you do a good cleanup, browser cache, maybe ccleaner and restart your machine ... that might take care of some ... be careful to insert the user root and a blank password for the database ...

Comment: I think I will come back to you much later. Right now localhost/tyo3cms takes me to uncaught exception.. So I think do a reinstall of xampp and start all over. Thanks for your patience and time

Comment: did you restart ? man you where 1 step away ... anyhow you understand know how to proceed, you'll see all will go in order ... are you from india ?

Comment: don't reinstall xampp, that gives you nothing, just empty the database with phpMyAdmin and redo the typo3 install from scratch ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126403/discussion-between-webman-and-zilore-mumba).